# PHP Razorpay payment through invoice

Tags: php, razorpay

i have integrated Razorpay in php, I'm sending invoice short_url link to customer to view/pay.
my question is,

1. whether there is any option to redirect to my application url once customer made payment through invoice (because i want to save payment related details in table)
2. is there any option to download invoice pdf in razorpay
3. or there is any option to stop/restrict payment option via invoice (so that i can send payment link to customer for payments)

Please help!!

Comment: 1. You'll need to subscribe to the relevant webhooks, https://razorpay.com/docs/payments/invoices/subscribe-to-webhooks/